# Detect shake gesture IOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, gesture

I'm developing a app with a gesture system, basically if I turn the iPhone to left my app will do a function, if I turn the iPhone to Right, other function, with others gestures.

I don't have idea how to work with that, i'm trying search in google but not work, the result is only touch gesture and not motion gesture.

someone have a tutorial to help me?

Comment: I suggest you are looking for Motion Events: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html

Answer (score 85):

Swift3 ios10:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.becomeFirstResponder() // To get shake gesture
}

// We are willing to become first responder to get shake motion
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}

// Enable detection of shake motion
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Why are you shaking me?")
    }
}
```

Comment: Good for Swift 4 and iOS 11!

Comment: Isn't resigning first responder required?  Like shown in the last part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47449094/897007

Answer (score 27):

Super easy to implement:

1) Let iOS know which view controller is the first in the responder chain:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
}   
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

2) Handle the event in some fashion:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake) {
        print("You shook me, now what")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 5**

Just add following methods to ViewController and execute the code

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?){
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Shake Gesture Detected")
        //show some alert here
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you override `canBecomeFirstResponder` instead of `becomeFirstResponder`?  This wasn't working for me until i changed that to `canBecomeFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 16):

This has been updated for IOS 12 - see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621090-motionended)
You no longer need to add becomeFirstResponder() method.

You just need to add motionEnded function to your code.

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) 
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Please provide proof or link to documentation about `becomeFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 5**
**iOS 10+**

`UIApplication`, `UIViewController`, `UIView`, and `UIWindow` are all `UIResponder` objects by default which means they can all handle motion events, like shake, without any special configuration. Therefore, simply override the appropriate motion method:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            print("device did shake")
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can override `motionBegan(_:with:)` and `motionCancelled(_:with:)`. And unlike overriding certain touch events, there is no need to call super.

Comment: this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            print("shake")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This only worked for me. Returning canBecomeFirstResponder as true did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Speedy99's swift answer is in the Objective C version

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return true;
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
       NSLog(@"Why are you shaking me?");
    }
}
```