# Flutter device shake iOS plugin

Tags: ios, swift, plugins, flutter, flutter-plugin

Evening guys,

Im looking into building a plugin for Flutter that detects if the device is shaking. Now i've found how to technically do it in Swift ([Detect shake gesture IOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503531/detect-shake-gesture-ios-swift)) but im stuck on how to hook it up as a Flutter plugin, because i don't have direct access to the view controller lifecycle events.

Need a way to hook up

- viewDidLoad
- canBecomeFirstResponder
- motionEnded

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Flutter Team* has already published [a plugin called `sensors`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sensors), which can be used to detect motion from the *accelerometer* (and gyroscope).

```
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';

accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
  // "calculate" "shakes" here
});
```

The `event` contains `x`, `y` and `z` values. Combining this with time will make it possible to check for shakes.

I am just pointing this out because it is way less to go than creating a ***full plugin*** from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, maybe thats even a better approach :-) Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

You could try this plugin: [shake_event](https://pub.dev/packages/shake_event/)

It's pretty simple to work with and works both for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, so I figured  `Reactive Programming` and `RxDart` could help.

You can create a `BLoC` (Business logic component) called `sensor_bloc.dart` :

```
 import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';

class SensorBloc {

  StreamSubscription<dynamic> _accelerometerStream;

  //INPUT
  final _thresholdController = StreamController<int>();
  Sink<int> get threshold => _thresholdController.sink;


  // OUTPUT
  final  _shakeDetector = StreamController<bool>();
  Stream<bool> get shakeEvent => _shakeDetector.stream.transform(ThrottleStreamTransformer(Duration(seconds: 2)));


  SensorBloc() {
    const CircularBufferSize = 10;
    double detectionThreshold = 70.0;

    List<double> circularBuffer = List.filled(CircularBufferSize,0.0);
    int index = 0;
    double minX=0.0, maxX=0.0;

    _thresholdController.stream.listen((value){
      // safety
      if (value > 30) detectionThreshold = value*1.0;
    });

    _accelerometerStream =  accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event){
        index = (index == CircularBufferSize -1 ) ? 0: index+1;

        var oldX = circularBuffer[index];

        if (oldX == maxX) {
          maxX = circularBuffer.reduce(max);
        }
        if (oldX == minX) {
          minX = circularBuffer.reduce(min);
        }

        circularBuffer[index] = event.x;
        if (event.x < minX ) minX=event.x;
        if (event.x> maxX) maxX = event.x;

        if (maxX-minX>detectionThreshold)
        {
          _shakeDetector.add(true);
          circularBuffer.fillRange(0, CircularBufferSize, 0.0);
          minX=0.0;
          maxX=0.0;
        }


    });

  }



  void dispose() {
    _shakeDetector.close();
    _accelerometerStream.cancel();
   _thresholdController.close();
  }
}
```

Then, just subscribe to its events in your widget :
Declare `StreamSubscription<bool> shakeSubscriber ;` in your state, and hook to lifecycle events

(NB:  I use a InheritedWidget giving me access to the umbrella BLoC via the static function  `MainWidget.bloc(context)`):

```
StreamSubscription<bool> shakeSubscriber ;      

@override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(shakeSubscriber == null ) {
      MainWidget.bloc(context).sensorBloc.shakeEvent.listen((_){
        print("SHAKE ! *************************");
      });

    }

    return _buildMainScaffold();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if(shakeSubscriber != null ) shakeSubscriber.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }
```